# Facebook Like Button on Blogger is showing total like count of the mainpage, but not of each individual article (for new articles)

Tags: html, facebook-like, blogger

So I'm trying to help a friend out with his Blogger blog and its integration with Facebook. He'd been having several issues (like a messed up og meta tags and what not) and we were finally able to get everything sorted, and running the site on Facebook's Debugger, everything came out fine. But now we have an issue where new posts show the overall likes of the main page, and not of each individual post for their Facebook Like buttons, while old posts are unaffected (have individual like counts.)

FYI, the site in question is [Los Heladeros](http://www.losheladeros.com/) (which apparently has around 87 likes at this point), and the Facebook site is /LOSH3LAD3ROS (which has 765 likes, so the likes aren't tied to the Facebook site, but rather the main page domain).

Now, we followed [this tutorial](http://www.bloggerplugins.org/2010/04/facebook-like-button-for-blogger.html) to create the code for the Like button to show up on each post (which it does, no problem). Here is the code for the button:

```
<div>
<b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost'> 
<script>(function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));</script>
</b:if> 
<fb:like expr:href="data:post.canonicalUrl" layout='standard' send='true' show_faces='false' font="lucida grande" action="like" colorscheme="light"></fb:like>
</div>
```

However, now, any new posts on the site are including the total likes for the main page (not the FB page), and not likes for the individual post (i.e., every new post starts off immediately with something like 87 likes at this point), yet all the old posts (before we fixed the Open Graph metadata issues) are perfectly fine (i.e., they show maybe a few likes, and are not affected by new likes or shares from the main page.)

*FYI, I've just noted that a post that was before the fix, and previously only showed a few shares, has now reverted to the overall count...*

Here's the Open Graph metadata for the site:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:version='2' class='v2' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr' xmlns:fb='http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml' xmlns:og='http://ogp.me/ns#'> 

<title>Los Heladeros: TU UPDATE MUSICAL ANTES QUE SE DERRITA</title>

<!-- Facebook Open Graph Meta Tags -->
<meta content='Los Heladeros' property='og:title'/>
<meta content='blog' property='og:type'/>
<meta content='http://www.losheladeros.com' property='og:url'/>
<meta content='https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/377165_310579818971632_1169246050_n.jpg' property='og:image'/>
<meta content='Los Heladeros' property='og:site_name'/>
<meta content='502365163' property='fb:admins'/>
<meta content='335887849786080' property='fb:app_id'/>
<meta content='Descargas gratis de música que no es cool, pero lo será mañana | HOUSE | INDIE | DISCO |' property='og:description'/>

<!-- Open Graph Meta Tags by: www.MetaTagGenerator.org -->
```

So I've read on other posts that you have to set the "**og:url**" to the specific site in question (i.e., every single post) and not the overall site, but isn't that what the "**data:post.canonicalUrl**" bit in the FB Like button code supposed to do? I know there has to be a way to have one universal code on the template page, and have the urls be pulled dynamically and the counts be individual for each post (and looking back at the old code before the meta tags were cleaned up, he had the same overall site URL as we have now, and never encountered this issue, so clearly before it was somehow working in a way).

Also, if I share any of the new articles, I subsequently get the picture and description of the main page, and not of the individual post, but when I share an old post, it auto generates the correct image and description. I've tried comparing the Facebook Debugger on both an old post and a new post and there is no discrepancy (as there shouldn't be any). I'm so confused as to what could possibly be doing this since it's a universal, over arching code, and I guess I would expect *ALL* posts to act the same way, and not just some (i.e., new and old).

FYI, since I'm a new user I can only post two links, but if you go to the main page, the newer posts are up top and have the 87+ like counts on the buttons and if you scroll down you'll eventually see older posts which have more modest counts (i.e., they're being counted correctly).

I would greatly appreciate any help you guys can give me. This is my first stackoverflow post, and I've read almost every single related post and still cannot find an answer to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I'm pretty much calling this one solved. I stumbled upon the following tutorial which details a thorough way of creating the correct Facebook Open Graph meta tags for Blogger:

[Open Graph markup for Blogger [version 3]](http://exde601e.blogspot.ro/2012/10/open-graph-markup-for-blogger-version-3.html)

Here are my updated meta tags, which seem to work perfectly fine going forward:

```
<!-- OPEN GRAPH MARKUP FOR BLOGGER [VER. 3] TAGS http://goo.gl/tyJ9a FOR ORIGINAL TUTORIAL -->
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/>    
<meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:site_name'/>     
<meta expr:content='data:blog.canonicalUrl' property='og:url'/>     
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription'>     
     <meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' property='og:description'/>     
</b:if>     
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>     
     <meta content='article' property='og:type'/>     
     <b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>     
         <meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>     
     </b:if>     
<b:else/>     
     <meta content='blog' property='og:type'/>     
     <meta content='https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/377165_310579818971632_1169246050_n.jpg' property='og:image'/>
     <meta content='502365163' property='fb:admins'/>
     <meta content='335887849786080' property='fb:app_id'/>     
</b:if>
<!-- OPEN GRAPH MARKUP FOR BLOGGER [VER. 3] TAGS http://goo.gl/tyJ9a FOR ORIGINAL TUTORIAL -->
```

Of note, I added the admin and app id at the bottom, indented under  and the Facebook Debugger/Linter seemed to be OK with that (before it gave me a warning that it was out of place). Also, my friend had a mismatch of APP IDs between the meta tags and the javascript implementation. I fixed that and put the same APP ID, and although the posts that were messed up are still messed up with their counts, going forward, all posts behave as they should with correct Like counts and when shared, the posts' info is correctly pulled into the share on FB (Title, Photo, Description).

Hope this helps anybody else who might be running into the same problem. Props to George B Moga. Here is the [stackoverflow post](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12805062/facebook-open-graph-tags-for-blogger) where I found his link to the template for the meta tags.